# Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ethernet, lan, gigabit-ethernet

I am currently on Windows 10 19043.1415 build. After the latest update of Windows, my Ethernet driver(Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller 10.54.1111.2021) suddenly stopped working. I tried recovering my OS to the previous build where the driver was working, I tried reinstalling the driver several times(both manually and by letting the system install the driver itself), but it always drops the same error:

> The driver for this device has been blocked from starting because it
> is known to have problems with Windows. Contact the hardware vendor
> for a new driver. (Code 48)

I have no idea what the problem is. Is there a way to fix this?

**UPD:** I have accidentally found a way to enable the Ethernet connection. By enabling the VPN(and connecting to Norway, while I remain in Russia), it magically detects the Ethernet connection. Still, I am looking for a solution to this, since it is quite uncomfortable to use VPN all the time.

Comment: Where are you downloading/installing the driver from? I suspect you'd need a newer version - try https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, I used the Win10 Auto Installation Program (NDIS) on this site.

Comment: My Realtek Gaming GbE NIC runs driver version 10.50.511.2021. Are you sure you've downloaded the Win10 installer package?

Comment: @Zac67 To be sure, I reinstalled the package, and now it is 10.54.1111.2021. However, the problem remains.

Comment: Have you verified that the NIC driver is on the same version (in Device Manager)?

Comment: @Zac67 I think so, but it turned out that the drivers' versions were not the problem. I have updated the question above according to what I've discovered.

Comment: How do you connect a VPN when the Ethernet NIC's out? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: @Zac67 Wi-Fi is still a thing

Comment: And the NIC's driver magically loads once the VPN is up? Could you be a filter driver mess with the VPN driver itself.

Answer (score 1):

check your dns setting in ethernet>properties>internet protocol version 4(tcp/ip)> here set to "obtain dns automatically".  i don't know how mine got changed?  i think it was installing anti-virus or something but my internet was only working with vpn enabled.  so try that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).